# C++ Application crashes once it memory usage reaches 1.5 GB

Tags: c++, windows

We have a C++ application running on Windows 32 bit system. It crashes once the memory usage reaches 1.5 GB. What we are unable to understand is why it's crashing at 1.5 GB limit and not at 2 GB limit (the virtual address space and windows 32 bit architecture limit)?

Other details:-
Total memory available : 4GB

Operating System : Windows XP

1.5 GB is the memory used by just this one process.

Regards,

Sachin

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you would EVER have an application that uses 1.5GB of memory... I'm drawing a blank. (P.S. I'm sure that your application isn't the ONLY thing running at that time)

Comment: How much memory does the system have in total?  Which version of Windows?

Comment: 1.5GB is the memory usage of what: the sole process or the whole system?

Comment: You want us to enumerate every possibities until we found the right one?

Comment: Total memory available : 4GB
Operating System : Windows XP
1.5 GB is the memory used by just this one process. Yes there are other processes running at the system. But shouldn't paging handle all that?

Comment: There are a whole host of potential causes for that crash, no answer that simply posited several options would even come close to being complete. We really need more information to solve this problem accurately. And just because 2 GB is the virtual address space limit for user-mode, 32-bit applications doesn't mean that your application can use all 2 GB of that with its own code. If you're using code from external libraries, that counts against you, too. Paging also won't help you if your total swap file size is less than 1.5 GB. Without the total RAM, we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Hi Cody, We use this C++ application to interact with Oracle database. So it uses other external libraries as well. Also we have 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: Why do you think it's because of memory? Have you caught std::bad_alloc?

Comment: @maxim1000 We fire requests on this application one by one on to this application. The request on which this crash happens is not same in every run. But one thing which is consistent is the memory usage of 1.5 GB.

Comment: Running out of AS is not the same thing as running out of VM, and you haven't told us what you are measuring and how you are measuring it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is perfectly normal under 32bit Windows.

Unless you have the /3gb switch activated, you have a total address space of 2GB. However, that's **minus** the mapped executable and at least half a dozen DLL and NLS files (for "hello world" -- a real application would probably have more like a dozen or two dozen of them).

Since they are not optimally placed, you lose about half a gigabyte of addres space. The heap will not grow "into" that region, and thus allocating more than 1.5GB will fail.

Here is what the address space of a "typical program" looks like:

[image]

Note how very skillfully one DLL is placed at about 1/3 of the address space, effectively "cutting off" a third of the memory that you can use.

Comment: Good answer, and bonus points for the screenshot. It would be helpful if you included a link to (or at least the name of) the utility you used to capture a graph of the address space fragmentation.

Comment: That's VMMap: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533

Answer (score 4):

The fragmentation of the virtual memory could be a reason.

One more possible reason is how memory managers (memory pools) are usually work. Memory manager attempts to reserve a block of memory 2 times more than the previous one. When memory is allocated already quite a lot, this amount will be very large and a memory allocation will fail despite the fact that in reality there is still available memory.

Comment: Apart from fragmentation, can other factory affect this? This crash happens is pretty consistent with that 1.5 GB memory limit. We have tried it running several times.

Comment: @sachin: Fragmentation is partially caused by DLL base addresses, which tend to be pretty consistent.  So that might explain why 1.5GB is so repeatable for you.

Comment: I have been googling this problem. One can find several queries where applications are crashing around 1.5 GB memory usage. Can there be some OS specific settings which force a 1.5 gb limit (and not 2 gb limit of windows xp) or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable dr. watson as default debugger and see if a crash dump could be catched, then open the dump with visual studio or windbg and you can see the callstack before crash, and then know what is the real cause of the crash.