# How to handle large amounts of data in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, memory-management, data-structures

I have data stored in several seperate text files that I parse and analyze afterwards.

The size of the data processed differs a lot. It ranges from a few hundred megabytes (or less) to 10+ gigabytes.

I started out with storing the parsed data in a `List<DataItem>` because I wanted to perform a `BinarySearch()` during the analysis. However, the program throws an OutOfMemory-Exception if too much data is parsed. The exact amount the parser can handle depends on the fragmentation of the memory. Sometimes it's just 1.5 gb of the files and some other time it's 3 gb.

Currently I'm using a `List<List<DataItem>>` with a limited number of entries because I thought it would change anything for the better. There weren't any significant improvements though.

Another way I tried was serializing the parser data and than deserializing it if needed. The result of that approach was even worse. The whole process took much longer.

I looked into memory mapped files but I don't really know if they could help me because I never used them before. Would they?

So how can I quickly access the data from all the files without the danger of throwing an `OutOfMemoryException` and find `DataItem`s depending on their attributes?

EDIT: The parser roughly works like this:

```
void Parse() {
   LoadFile();
   for (int currentLine = 1; currentLine < MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES; ++currentLine) {
      string line = GetLineOfFile(currentLine);
      string[] tokens = SplitLineIntoTokens(line);
      DataItem data = PutTokensIntoDataItem(tokens);
      try {
         List<DataItem>.Add(data);
      } catch (OutOfMemoryException ex) {}
   }
}

void LoadFile(){
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectroyInfo(Path); 
 FileInfo[] fileList = di.GetFiles(); 
 foreach(FileInfo fi in fileList) 
 { 
  //... 
  StreamReader file = new SreamReader(fi.FullName); 
  //... 
  while(!file.EndOfStram) 
   strHelp = file.ReadLine(); 
  //...
 }
}
```

Comment: can you post your parsing routine?

Comment: This question is overly broad. Please narrow down your question and provide the code sample causing the problem. Best regards,

Comment: Are you possibly running this under 32-bit Windows? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684846/c-application-crashes-once-it-memory-usage-reaches-1-5-gb

Comment: Also, if you're trying to load 10+Gb worth of data into memory when you only have 8Gb, you will get an OOM exception.  There isn't really any way around that.

Comment: I added the code sample.
There is no problem with the parsing as such. The way I'm stroing the data afterwards is the problem. @Krishna

Comment: The per process limit is 3gb is it not?

Comment: I'm running 64-bit Windows and how do I do it without loading that much data into memory? @WyattEarp

Comment: I am keen to see your LoadFile() - do you readLine or readall. ReadAll is hungry,

Comment: @Adam - x64 has a theoretical uplimit of 8TB per process.

Comment: I didn't know he was using x64, thanks though :)

Comment: The code sample I posted isn't the actual code, I only used it  for illustration. Just wanted to clarify that. But the way the Files are loaded goes something like this:
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectroyInfo(Path); FileInfo[] fileList = di.GetFiles(); foreach(FileInfo fi in fileList) { ... StreamReader file = new SreamReader(fi.FullName); ... while(!file.EndOfStram) strHelp = file.ReadLine(); ...}
So I'm using ReadLine() 
 @Krishna

Comment: I won't load any huge file in memory unless someone is pointing me a gun. With such a files, I'd rather consider an indexing (which can be a random-access file), then an access to the textfile as "binary" (i.e. random access, again). Not easy, though, but I think there's no options...

Comment: sorry @Adam I missed the order of comments here...

Answer (score 2):

There is no right answer for this I believe. The implementation depends on many factors that only you can rate pros and cons on.

If your primary purpose is to parse large files and large number of them, keeping these in memory irrespective of how much RAM is available should be a secondary option, for various reasons for e.g. like persistance at times when an unhandled exception occured.

Although when profiling under initial conditions you may be encouraged and inclined to load them to memory retain for manipulation and search, this will soon change as the number of files increase and in no time your application supporters will start ditching this.

I would do the below

1. Read and store each file content to a document database like Raven DB for e.g.
2. Perform parse routine on these documents and store the relevant relations in an rdbms db if that is the requirement
3. Search at will, fulltext or otherwise, on either the document db (raw) or relational (your parse output)

By doing this, you are taking advantage of research done by the creators of these systems in managing the memory efficiently with focus on performance

I realise that this may not be the answer for you, but for someone who may think this is better and suits perhaps yes.

Answer (score 1):

If the code in your question is representative of the actual code, it looks like you're reading all of the data from all of the files into memory, and then parsing. That is, you have:

```
Parse()
    LoadFile();
    for each line
        ....
```

And your `LoadFile` loads all of the files into memory. Or so it seems. That's very wasteful because you maintain a list of all the un-parsed lines in addition to the objects created when you parse.

You could instead load only one line at a time, parse it, and then discard the unparsed line. For example:

```
void Parse()
{
    foreach (var line in GetFileLines())
    {
    }
}

IEnumerable<string> GetFileLines()
{
    foreach (var fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path))
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

That limits the amount of memory you use to hold the file names and, more importantly, the amount of memory occupied by un-parsed lines.

Also, if you have an upper limit to the number of lines that will be in the final data, you can pre-allocate your list so that adding to it doesn't cause a re-allocation. So if you know that your file will contain no more than 100 million lines, you can write:

```
void Parse()
{
    var dataItems = new List<DataItem>(100000000);
    foreach (var line in GetFileLines())
    {
        data = tokenize_and_build(line);
        dataItems.Add(data);
    }
}
```

This reduces fragmentation and out of memory errors because the list is pre-allocated to hold the maximum number of lines you expect. If the pre-allocation works, then you know you have enough memory to hold references to the data items you're constructing.

If you still run out of memory, then you'll have to look at the structure of your data items. Perhaps you're storing too much information in them, or there are ways to reduce the amount of memory used to store those items. But you'll need to give us more information about your data structure if you need help reducing its footprint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- [Data Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx)
- [Write a Simple Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx)

I think it will make it will reduce memory exception and make files handling faster.